# Reducing the number of equations in a system

Tags: asymptotics, systems-of-equations, computer-science, computational-complexity

Suppose I have a system of $2^{2^{n(n-1)}}-2$ equations and I show that it is equivalent to a system of $n\times (2^{2^{n-1}}-2)$ equations.

Is there any synthetic notion that can capture such a reduction?

I understand that we cannot use the "order of computational complexity" notion as I haven't said anything about the characteristics of the equations, but I was wondering whether there is something similar that can help here.

Comment: What does "synthetic notion" mean? The number of equations is reduced by a huge factor (initially I thought that is was $2^{2^n}/n$ times but it's more than that). That's a simple and concrete quantitative measure. What else are you looking for? Computational complexity to solve these equations? Space to just write them down?

Comment: The factor of reduction in of the order $2^{2^{(n-1)(n-1)}}/n$

Comment: Are the $n \times (2^{2^{n - 1}} - 2)$ equations "simpler" or "more complex" than the original system? For examples, if the length of the equations has an exponential blowup, then maybe it is even harder to solve than the original system. Length of an equation is certainly not a good measure of the complexity though...

Comment: Thanks, @AlexVong what do you mean by `` Length of an equation''?

Comment: Here's the point: the equations that I am considering cannot be solved analytically but only numerically: I write the whole vector of equations in Matlab and, then, given a pre-defined grid of parameters, I check whether each parameter value in the grid can be a solution of the system of equations by substituting it to the unknown. Now, ``writing the whole vector of equations in Matlab'' can be an unmanageable step if the number of equations is $2^{2^{n(n-1)}}-2$ and $n=5$. That's why I care about reducing the length of the system. I am looking for some help on how to formally explain this.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a linear system? I think solving a linear system has time complexity of $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ where $n$ is the size of the matrix using Gaussian elimination. I don't know if you can do better though.

Comment: @Thanassis How did you get $2^{2^{(n-1)(n-1)}}/n$

Comment: @Thanassis If I solve the equation $n\times (2^{2^{n-1}}-2)\times x=2^{2^{n(n-1)}}-2$, I get $x=\frac{1}{n}\frac{2^{2^{n(n-1)}}-2}{2^{2^{n-1}}-2}>>\frac{1}{n}2^{2^{(n-1)(n-1)}}$

Comment: I don't remember what I did, but I was trying to get to a simpler form of the fraction $\frac{2^{2^{n(n-1)}}-2}{2^{2^{n-1}}-2}$ You can safely ignore the -2s. You are right, the result is much closer to $2^{2^{n(n-1)}}$ than $2^{2^{(n-1)(n-1)}}$ But if you are writing in big-O notation then the order is $O(2^{2^{n^2}})$

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you what is the meaning of big O notation in this case? It is not related to computing time, correct? It is just related to the "length" of this sequence of equations, correct? Also, should I write $O(2^{2^{n^2}})$ or $O(2^{2^{(n-1)^2}}/n)$ as you suggested above?